# Combine query_posts() and get_posts() into single query

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts, get-posts

I am creating a site which uses normal posts for a blog and the a custom post type for events(generated by the events plugin). I have successfuly used different queries to grab both but I want to combine them into one query. Have tried various things with no luck.

Here is query for blog:

```
<?php $mainFeatures = array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'order'=> 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'post_date');
 $postslist = get_posts( $mainFeatures );
 foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>            
      <!-- stuff from post-->
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Here is query for events:

```
 <?php query_posts(array('post_type'=>array(TribeEvents::POSTTYPE), 'numberposts' => -1,'order' => 'ASC')); ?>
 <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <!-- stuff from post-->
 <?php endwhile;?>
```

Have tried this but again only gets the events:

```
 <?php $tryone = query_posts(array('post_type'=>post, 'posts_per_page'=> 18)); ?>
 <?php $trytwo = query_posts(array('post_type'=>array(TribeEvents::POSTTYPE))); ?>
 <?php $all_posts = array_merge( $tryone, $trytwo ); ?>

 <?php query_posts($all_posts); ?>
 <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
 <p>stuff</p>
 <?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: One has a `DESC` order and the other is `ASC`.  I don't think you an do both, but otherwise you can pass an array of post types to the `post_type` parameter.

Comment: @helgatheviking i tried this but it only pulled the events, not the normal posts: <?php $args = array('post_type'=>array('posts', TribeEvents::POSTTYPE)); ?>
<?php query_posts($args); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<p>test</p>
<?php endwhile;?>

Comment: That's because the `post` post type is simply `post` and not the plural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong `post_type` for regular posts.

```
$args = array('post_type'=>array('post', TribeEvents::POSTTYPE));  

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
endwhile;

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Cheers, it seems to work but only grabs the events and posts in limited number, it onl gets a total of 4 whereas there is 18 posts and 2 events.

Comment: Edit the answer to use the proper `WP_Query()` instead of `query_posts()`, and I'll upvote. :)

Comment: Good point @ChipBennett.  Done.

Comment: Upvoted. :) Note: you don't need to call `wp_reset_query()`, since you're no longer touching the main query. Calling `wp_reset_postdata()` suffices.

Comment: cheers for the help, that worked great - I just realised that the limit of 4 was being caused by the basic reading settings in wordpress duh.

Comment: Thanks Chip. Edited again.  I pulled that almost directly from the Codex, so I will make the edit there too.  @PaulElliot Everyone has a face palm moment now and then.  You can adjust the limit with the `posts_per_page` parameter, otherwise it defaults to your reading setting.